# How to edit files in a Confluence docker container? There is no vim and apt-get in it

Tags: vim, docker, confluence

I have pull a Confluence image by this command:

```
docker pull cptactionhank/atlassian-confluence
```

And also execute following commands to run the Confluence container:

```
$ docker run --detach --publish 8091:8091 -i -t cptactionhank/atlassian-confluence:5.8.6
=>Container id is b2286f9ab2318d2461acc96e45514b4dd737af96
$ docker exec -ti b2286f9ab2318d2461acc96e45514b4dd737af96 /bin/bash
```

After above commands, I can enter the container, but there is no vim in it, and no apt-get to install vim.

How could I edit the files in the container? Thanks.

I found the solution, just enter the docker with root status:

```
$ docker exec -ti --name root b2286f9ab2318d2461acc96e45514b4dd737af96 /bin/bash
```

Then install vim:

```
$ apt-get install vim
```

Then I can edit files.

Comment: Is there nano? "Comments must be at least 15 characters in length"

Comment: No nano, pico, vi, vim and apt-get.

Comment: You should move your answer into an answer, instead of in the question.

Comment: How to move it to an answer?

Comment: Just edit the question and remove the answer part, then put that into an answer instead (scroll down). After 2 days, you can mark it as accepted, if you want to.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Find the solution, just enter the docker with root status:

```
$ docker exec -ti --name root b2286f9ab2318d2461acc96e45514b4dd737af96 /bin/bash
```

Then install vim:

```
$ apt-get installl vim
```

Then I can edit files.

Answer (score 0):

docker exec -ti **--user** root b2286f9ab2318d2461acc96e45514b4dd737af96 /bin/bash

not **--name**